# hiding selected worksheets without for loop

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to hide some worksheets, all at once, without using for loop. The reason for this is a big number of worksheets, so my macro works a while.

Do you have any ideas how can I improve the running time of this macro?

Comment: Why don't you want to use a for loop?

Comment: The loop by itself doesn't add that much overhead. Your code will run in just about the same time with or without loop.

Comment: Also, posting your code would help.

Comment: i came up with the same idea as Slai, to hide sheets all at once and it helped me, i saved like 10 seconds. I project this file to be user friendly and if possible, I want it to work as fast as possible. Could you please explain, why did you mark my questions as not useful? :)

Answer (score 4):

You can just record a macro of selecting the first sheet, and then select the last sheet with Shift. Then you right-click and Hide.

```
Sheets(Array("Sheet2", "Sheet3", "Sheet4")).Visible = False
```

Or by index

```
Sheets([{2, 3, 4}]).Visible = False
```

Note that you can not **un**hide more than one sheet at a time.

---

To add a custom view with all sheets visible:

```
For Each ws In Sheets
    ws.Visible = True
Next
ActiveWorkbook.CustomViews.Add "All"  ' you can change the name
```

Then, to un-hide all sheets:

```
ActiveWorkbook.CustomViews("All").Show
```

---

To un-hide the sheets faster, you can try disabling some of the events and calculation:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

For Each ws In Sheets: ws.Visible = True: Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
```

Comment: thanks for the help, I got similar outcome with registering macro and selecting all 200 sheets :) Unfortunately, as you said, i can't unhide more than one sheet at a time :( Therefore, everytime I open the file i lose 10 seconds :( 
Maybe you have an idea how can I make clients to enable macros in other way than hiding and unhiding all sheets? :) (sorry for my bad english)

Comment: You can do it with custom view http://www.accountingweb.com/technology/excel/hide-and-unhide-multiple-excel-worksheets

Comment: Hiding sheets will not make your file open faster. You can try saving the file as .xlsb

Comment: thanks, do you think it is possible to save somehow with vba all unhidden sheets as a custom view, and then, after opening the workbook again, come back to last view? Unfortunately I have problems with registering on this website, so I cant read the rest of this article.. :(

Comment: I dont want my sheet to open faster because my sheets are hidden, i just want the macro, which unhides the sheets to work faster (i have 200 sheets, unhiding all with a for loop takes 10 seconds, which is long in this situation)

Comment: Thanks for all your help:) I came up with an idea to write a code like this:
    ActiveWorkbook.Windows(1).Visible = False
    ActiveWorkbook.Windows(1).Visible = True
But when i hide a workbook i cant target it with ActiveWorkbook.Windows(1). Maybe you know how can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub HideSheets()

    Dim sSheets() As String

    sSheets = Split("Sheet1,Sheet2,Sheet3", ",")

    Worksheets(sSheets).Visible = xlHidden

End Sub
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13071197)

Comment: @CryptoGuy - why did you place this comment here? I am not seeing the relation?

Comment: It was set from template (through review). You are more experienced user on SO and should know that link-only and code-only (without explanation or description) aren't appreciated here.

Comment: Fair enough for the lack of explanation @CryptoGuy